# Revit Design Automation fails with -1073740791 error

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I ran a new job on design automation and it failed with -1073740791 error code. The job id is:

"Id":"3991468c840243a39ad95903f94a58b6"

The full error report is:

```
[06/13/2022 09:23:22] End Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
[06/13/2022 09:23:22] Error: Application revitcoreconsole.exe exits with code -1073740791 which indicates an error.
[06/13/2022 09:23:22] End script phase.
[06/13/2022 09:23:22] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[06/13/2022 09:23:22] Job finished with result FailedExecution
[06/13/2022 09:23:22] Job Status:
```

What does -1073740791 error code mean specifically?

Comment: Thanks for reporting. It is very possible that something went wrong when Revit processed the job. But unfortunately, we cannot read more than you can find in the report.log, so I cannot tell the fundamental issue. The same suggestions will help the diagnosis: 1. try the same addin and input file in Desktop Revit with local debugging tool: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-csharp-revit.local.debug.tool to see if the addin can succeed with this big input file; 2. share the activity definition, addin source code and input file with us so we can try to reproduce.

Comment: I just looked more on EC2 machines, actually, I think the this error is very like caused by running out of memory too, but different is in this case, machine is not down.

Comment: Ok thanks. That's helpful in one case where I got this error there was also this line in the logs:
Failure #0: FailureDefinitionId-'946a7365-7750-4cc4-b632-48391f518b86', Severity-'DocumentCorruption', Description-'A serious error has occurred. It is strongly recommended that you use Save As to save your work in a new file before continuing.', Resolution-'Save File And Continue'.